# How can I hyphenate words with dots in a \texttt environment in LaTeX?

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation, typewriter, hyphenat

There is a bunch of discussions online how to enable (or disable) hyphenation in \texttt environments. I found both the options

```
\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}
```

and

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\mytexttt}{\ttfamily\hyphenchar\font=45\relax}
```

to work. However, what still does not work is to put a line break into a term such as \texttt{ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore()}. I don't care that there might be rules that suggest not to line break code and want LaTeX to be able to output, for example,

```
... ee.Algorithms
.Landsat.simpleCloudScore() ...
```

The solutions discussed for words with dashes won't work, and there is surprisingly little to be found for "my" problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split at periods and then reinserting them with a penalty in front and the possibility to hyphenate the following part.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}

\newcommand{\breakingperiod}{%
  \penalty0 % allow a break before the period
  .\nobreak\hspace{0pt}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\longword}{m}
 {
  \texttt
   {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_michael_lw_seq { . } { #1 }
    \seq_use:Nn \l_michael_lw_seq { \breakingperiod }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}%
  \longword{ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore()}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\parbox` trick allows to see all break points.

Comment: This solution worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

various possibilities, depending on whether you want a break at a `.` to be hyphenated

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}


\newcommand\zz[1]{\par\bigskip\fbox{\parbox{#1}{\ttfamily\hyphenchar\font=`\-\lccode`\.=`\.
a Something.Landsat.simpleCloudScore()}}}

\zz{20em}

\zz{15em}

\zz{10em}

\zz{5em}

\catcode`.=\active
\edef\.{\string.}
\renewcommand\zz[1]{\par\bigskip\fbox{\parbox{#1}{\ttfamily\hyphenchar\font=`\-\def.{\string.\hspace{0pt}}%
a Something.Landsat.simpleCloudScore()}}}

\zz{20em}

\zz{15em}

\zz{10em}

\zz{5em}
\catcode`.=12


\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution seems that the \zz command takes a width parameter - and I don't want to specify any width and would much rather have fully automatic hyphenation. Or am I misunderstanding the solution?

Comment: @Michael sorry you misundersttod (I should have been clearer) the `\zz` is just a test command that sets the text at the specified width in a `\fbox` so that you can see different linebreaking, you would not use that at all in a real document.